# I'm getting an IndexOutOfRangeExcpectation on my unity code (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, index-error

Here's the code, i'm a beginner and I've been stuck on this for a long time, unity console says "IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array." I need to add more text to this for stackoverflow to let me post so scroll down for the code and ignore the following spam text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Animator anim;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float jumpForce;
    public float playerSpeed;
    public Vector2 jumpHeight;
    private bool isOnGround;
    public float positioinRadius;
    public LayerMask ground;
    public Transform playerPos;



    void Start()
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Collider2D>();
        for (int i = 0; 1 < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int k = i + 1; k < colliders.Length; k++)
            {
                Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(colliders[i], colliders[k]);
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0)
            {
                anim.Play("Walk");
                rb.AddForce(Vector2.right * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                anim.Play("WalkBackwards");
                rb.AddForce(Vector2.left * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            anim.Play("Idle");
        }

        isOnGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(playerPos.position, positioinRadius, ground);
        if (isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _1 < colliders.Length_ 1(One) not letter i

Comment: In general you might rather want to use layers and ignore all collision with the layer itself